# Primavera not working on my system in the office

Tags: primavera, remedy

How to make back up of projects in Primavera, if suddenly it (a user) is logged out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question.  You can backup the database itself using Oracle or Sql Server backup tools.  All the data is in the db, so everything you need is there.

But sounds like you have application issues if you cannot log in, or are kicked out suddenly.